# TypeError: delete_dog() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Dog_id' How do I get around this?

Tags: python, sql, flask

I have written this code and have gotten this TypeError and don't understand the error. What am I doing wrong.

```
    
@app.route("/deletedog", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def delete_dog(Dog_id):
    p=dog.query.filter_by(Dog_id=Dog_id).first()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        db.session.delete(p)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("deletedog.html")
```

`

Im kinda of scratching my head i didn't think it needs a positional

Answer (score 2):

You can't get `Dog_id` from the function parameter if you want to support both `GET` and `POST`. You need to use `request.form` or `request.args.get()`.

```
@app.route("/deletedog", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def delete_dog():
    if request.method  == 'POST':
        Dog_id = request.form['dog_id']
    else:
        Dog_id = request.args.get('dog_id')
    p=dog.query.filter_by(Dog_id=Dog_id).first()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        db.session.delete(p)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("deletedog.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

You told flask that you were passing parameter in the route but you didn't.

```py
@app.route("/deletedog<Dog_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def delete_dog(Dog_id=2342):
    p=dog.query.filter_by(Dog_id=Dog_id).first()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        db.session.delete(p)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("deletedog.html")
```

Comment: I don't think putting the parameter in the route works for POST.

Comment: Sure, I think he should handled that

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are making a Flask app, kindly, next time include those details in your question. To add parameters to a flask app you need to include in the route URL the request, so changing the route url to something like `/deletedog/<dog_id>` should make this to work.